# How to uninstall Ganache

Tags: solidity

I have been trying to find the ganache in the control panel and uninstalled it. However, I just couldn't find it. Anyone knows how to uninstall it, or just removed the directory instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use windown10 and I find ganache with "windown + S". Then you right-click on the ganache icon to see the uninstall option Or you can uninstall with control panel